# Why do I get an Unable to connect to the remote server exception from a web app and not console app?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a asmx web service running on a test server that has anonymous access enabled.

When I add the web reference to a console application and call a simple Hello World method like so:

```
PivotService.PivotService p = new PivotService.PivotService();
String s = p.SayHello();
```

When I do exactly the same thing in the page load of a web application I get a `System.Net.WebException: {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}`.

The inner exception is `{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"}`, errorCode 10061.

Why would this work from a console app and not a web app?

Comment: I was getting this message while was connected to the VPN

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It could be due to differences in the proxy settings between applications. Check out the MSDN documentation around the [Default Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) element in config file.

Comment: There was no defaultProxy element in either the app.config or web.config. Added it to the web.config and set enabled=false. Fixed the problem :) thanks

Comment: Thank you!! I was going crazy over this, it was all my own doing however. I had created a proxy entry to filter traffic through to fiddler. After a while away from the code I returned to it an encountered this error, Fiddler was not open hence the proxy was failing. Thanks again!

Comment: Strange. I had to add it with default="true". Luckily after some hours it works :)

Answer (score 16):

I too was in a similar situation while using `HttpClient` class from `System.Net.Http` namespace. I was trying to make a network call which goes through the company proxy server.

While this `HttpClient` call was able to successfully resolve the IP of the dns when called from a console app in visual studio the dns resolution failed when the call was made from a Web API. And it turned out that I had to have this entry in the web.config of the web api app.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy />
</system.net>
```

Credit to Mark 909's answer for pointing me in right direction. Please see [Default Proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) for additional information.

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient)[webapi](/questions/tagged/webapi)

Comment: This fixed my issue. It started hapenning after I changed my methods to async.

Comment: This one worked for me too! With postman my POST requests went through however in api application from Visual Studio I was getting connection errors.

Answer (score 1):

First remove web reference from console
run you web service and copy the URL
go to your solution explorer and add web reference(Exclude old one)>Advanced>Add web Reference 
add paste URL then add your web reference name then rebuild your solution
it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

As @R Kiran Kumar suggests, I had to also add the proxy values:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False"
             proxyaddress="Specify Your Proxy Address: Specify Port Number"
             // Example, "http://192.168.0.10:1234"
bypassonlocal="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line :

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Just above the `httpclient` object creation